# Is this the correct way to make an ERC-20 backed by other coins?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, trading

I'm new to smart contract development and wanted to make a coin that functions like an index for my favorite coins. I'm new to smart contract development and was wondering how I could do this such that it's programmatically verifiable that an ERC-20 coin is worth U, V, and X cryptocurrencies. I was thinking that users deposit currency which is then swapped for the currencies backing the ERC-20 coin. The backing currencies are then stored in the smart contract and each ERC-20 token may be exchanged for some fixed amount of each backing currency. I know this is pretty complicated but wanted to make sure I was on the right track. Is this how a coin like this should be set up?

Comment: I am not getting you, are you trying to say if some deposit eth into your contract wo will give tokens which are connected with your contract ??!! or please elaborate